# Inserting columns

Tags: excel, vba

I tried with both relative cell references and absolute references. I tried recording a macro and writing it in VBA.

It is supposed to take raw data and format it. This includes inserting two new columns to add Notes.

I have included a snip of the macro. I know the problem is not with the rest of the macro because the issue happens when I use this alone.

```
Rows("1:1").Select
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Selection.ClearFormats
Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("B3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Date"
Range("F3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Notes"
```

Comment: I have a feeling it's related to using `.Select`. It's ***highly*** suggested to [avoid doing so](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros).

Comment: Thank you. I will try.  I am a total novice.. I am looking at how to use Activate and variables but I doubt I will be able to figure out how to use those to do the same thing without hitting many brick walls along the way. Ah well.

Comment: We all hit brick walls to get to where we are, and expect to hit many more. The key is to realize you can go around/through the walls by digging around, asking questions, and trying alternatives.

Comment: Ha! I think I have got something!' `Range("B1").EntireColumn.Insert
    Range("A1").EntireRow.Insert` :) Seems to work well enough I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should probably help, i hope

```
Private Sub thisorthat()
Sheets(6).Columns("B").EntireColumn.Insert
End Sub
```

Comment: Ha, nice catch!

Comment: I shouldve read the comments before blindly posting, OP was very close already. @BruceWayne

Comment: And I should've read the code instead of blindly saying it's probably due to `.Select`, :P